# how to add a prefix to Magento product URL’s in magento 1.9.2.1?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, frontend

Adding a Prefix to Product URL’s in Magento

I have follow below  instructions but its not showing prefix product url.Can anyone help me For this?

Copy:

**/app/code/core/mage/catalog/model/url.php**

To:

**/app/code/local/mage/catalog/model/url.php**

**Replace :**

```
if ($category->getLevel() > 1) {
           // To ensure, that category has path either from attribute or generated now
           $this->_addCategoryUrlPath($category);
           $categoryUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($category->getUrlPath(),
               false, $storeId);
           $requestPath = $categoryUrl . '/' . $urlKey;
       } else {
           $requestPath = $urlKey;
       }
```

**To:**

```
if ($category->getLevel() > 1) {
            // To ensure, that category has path either from attribute or generated now
            $this->_addCategoryUrlPath($category);
            $categoryUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($category->getUrlPath(),
                false, $storeId);
            $requestPath = 'product-p/' .$categoryUrl . '/' . $urlKey;
        } else {
            $requestPath = 'product-p/' .$urlKey;
        }
}
```